# SQL Sub Queries/Self Join

Tags: sql-server, subquery, self-join

This is an automatic call feedback database that stores customer feedback against every question.

I am using SQL Server 2012 I have the following data in table name **[NPS_Feedback]**:

```
CLI         CallerID    Customer_Account    Question    Feedback        Date
34622968    F22141B854  400004775250        Q1          Satisfie        2016-03-25
34622968    F22141B854  400004775250        Q2          Not Satisfied   2016-03-25
34622968    F22141B854  400004775250        Q3          Not Satisfied   2016-03-25
30227453    GED903EDL   400001913180        Q1          Not Satisfied   2016-03-25
30227453    GED903EDL   400001913180        Q2          Satisfied       2016-03-25
30227453    GED903EDL   400001913180        Q3          Not Satisfied   2016-03-25
34622968    DAED19FDE   400004775250        Q1          Satisfied       2016-03-25
34622968    DAED19FDE   400004775250        Q2          Satisfied       2016-03-25
34622968    DAED19FDE   400004775250        Q3          Satisfied       2016-03-25
```

Please help me with the following desire output for **Reports** using SQLstored procedure:

```
CLI     CallerID        Customer_Account    Q1             Q2             Q3              Date
34622968    F22141B854  400004775250        Satisfied      Not-Satisfied  Not-Satisfied   2016-03-25
30227453    GED903EDL   400001913180        Not-Satisfied  Satisfied      Not-Satisfied   2016-03-25
34622968    DAED19FDE   400004775250        Satisfied      Satisfied      Satisfied       2016-03-25
```

**Please Note:**

> Caller ID is Unique here for every call.

Comment: check out PIVOT operator

Comment: Use PiVOT. is  Q1,Q2,Q3 fix or there can be more feedback type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using the `PIVOT` command, you could also use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    CLI, 
    CallerID, 
    Customer_Account, 
    Q1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Q1' THEN Feedback END),
    Q2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Q2' THEN Feedback END),
    Q3 = MAX(CASE WHEN Question = 'Q3' THEN Feedback END),
    Date
FROM NPS_Feedback 
GROUP BY
    CLI, CallerID, Customer_Account, Date
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/478016)</kbd>

Comment: Sir I need all of them in a single line...!

Comment: @BilalAhmed, what's the problem with my answer? Check the demo.

Comment: Thank you Sir it was my mistake I had DateTime and the Time was different that is why it was showing each record in separate line. Marking this as Answer...!

Answer (score 0):

A simple PIVOT query will work.

```
select CLI,CallerID,Customer_Account, [Q1],[Q2],[Q3], Date
from
(
    select 
    CLI,CallerID,Customer_Account,Question,Feedback,Date
    from [NPS_Feedback]
)s
pivot
(
    max(Feedback) for Question in ([Q1],[Q2],[Q3])
) p
```

Comment: Please review it says ( Incorrect syntax near 'p' )

Comment: Dear it is showing records in different line each.. Please guide me to show screenshot. Is it possible to attach Screenshot here..??

Comment: @BilalAhmed This cannot happen. You must be missing something

Comment: Thank you Sir it was my mistake I had DateTime and the Time was different that is why it was showing each record in separate line.

Comment: @BilalAhmed So do you want to ignore time part?

Comment: I will handle it Sir, Thank you.